# Проблема с WI FI

Tags: wifi

На ноутбуке перестал работать wi-fi.

Причем отказывается работать даже после переустановки ОС.

Дело в том что в адаптерах, драйвер WI-FI всегда подсвечивается желтым трехугольником и пишет (This device cannot start (code 10)

Удалось как-то запустить адаптер, но тогда пишет что устройство работает нормально, но проблема в том что оно не находит ни одну сеть ! т.е как бы адаптер работает но сеть не сканирует.

Раньше такого не было сколько раз переустанавливал всегда все работало.

Самое интересное то что проблема пришла внезапно, т.е все работало, а потом резко перестало. И с тех пор не хочет ни в какую работать.

Может это проблема техническая ?

Comment: скорее проблема в драйвере ...

Comment: Как это возможно, 20 раз устанавливал один и тот же драйвер, а теперь нужен новый ?

Comment: В самом начале загрузки ноутбука BOIS ничего не пишет типа Device Invalid? (в верхнем левом углу). Надпись появляется буквально на пару секунд. Если так пишет - 100% накрылся WiFi модуль. Если нет, то проверить, включен ли WiFi в BIOS и/или хардварным переключателем. Хотя по симптомам - хана WiFi модулю.

Comment: Нет не пишет, он его обнаруживает, но всегда висит значек восклицательного знака. В общем какие бы драйвера не ставил, он не работает. Модуль думаю скоро достанут, проверим. Скажу что накрылся он быстро, так как WI FI практически никогда не пользовался :)